# Flexbox and overflow:scroll

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to get these elements with 25% width inside a flexbox and with `overflow-x:scroll`. There will be more then 4 elements so my aim is to get 25% per each of the first 4, the rest to be scrollable. My current setup doesn't return 25% per each element. Could you please help me.

Thanks.

```css
#wrapper {
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cont25 {
  width: 25%;
  background: black;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: 10px;
  max-height: 280px;
  flex: none;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

#novinky .flex {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="outterBox" id="novinky">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the `width` to `25%`, but forgot about margins. You can get this 4 items fully displayed with a small calculation of width: `width: calc(25% - 20px);`, where `20px` is the sum of left and right `margin` of each item. Here is an example:

```css
#wrapper {
  padding: 0 10px;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.cont25 {
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  background: black;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: 10px;
  max-height: 280px;
  flex: none;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}

#novinky .flex {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="outterBox" id="novinky">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
      <div class="cont25">
        <p>25%</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There you go. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you also added on a 10px margin.  Change your width to this to your `.cont25` div and I think you will get what you are looking for.

```
width: calc(25% - 20px);
```

```css
#wrapper {
  padding:0 10px;
  max-width:1400px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
.cont25 {
  width: calc(25% - 20px);
  background: black;
  height: 20vw;
  margin: 10px;
  max-height: 280px;
  flex: none;
}

.flex {
  display:flex;
}

#novinky .flex {
  overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="outterBox" id="novinky">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
      <div class="cont25"><p>25%</p></div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```